# How to create 'magic quadrant' style chart using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

Do you guys know of an ASP.Net chart control I can use to create [Gartner's Magic Quadrant](http://www.gartner.com/DisplayDocument?doc_cd=131166)-style charts?

I also want bubble sizes to reflect the market volume for each data point.

As we are on a tight schedule, we do not have the option of rolling out our own custom solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASP.NET Charting Control provides advanced charting graphs. [Scott Gu provided a really nice overview along with valuable links.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

If you are familiar with Dundas, you will find the FREE ASP.NET Charting Control is very similiar to MS's offering.  Why? [Microsoft acquired Dundas Data Visualization Intellectual Property in April 2007 and is integrating this technology in different Microsoft products.](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexgor/archive/2008/11/07/microsoft-chart-control-vs-dundas-chart-control.aspx)

Review Scott Gu's post and [Download the Microsoft Chart Controls Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591) project to see what ASP.NET Charting Control can do. I also recommend looking at the [Gallery at Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/Gallery/Flash/) too.

Best of luck.